# Unauthorized Error 401 while making Batch request to MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have an app that is being migrated to MS Graph API to read Email , do some processing and then move them Different folder. We are able to connect to MS Graph and do the said operations in sequential manner. However , we would like to process them in batches to reduce network calls and latency.

We are developing JAVA app using MSAL4J libraries and referring link : : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/graphapi-batching/batching-requests-to-msgraph/ to create batch requests.

However , when we send batch request, we are getting below error ( Even with single request to fetch user details )

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized, url=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch}

API/ Permission added are Mail.ReadWrite with Admin consent and User.Read
May you please let us know if any other settings are needed for Batch processing to work?

Thank you.

EDIT 1:

Here is the code which returned the above response

```
Request userRequest = new Request.Builder().url(graphClient.me().getRequestUrl()).build();
    MSBatchRequestStep userRequestStep = new MSBatchRequestStep("1", userRequest, null);
    
    
    // Create the batch request content with the steps created above
    List<MSBatchRequestStep> batchSteps = Arrays.asList(userRequestStep);
    MSBatchRequestContent batchRequestContent = new MSBatchRequestContent(batchSteps);

    ICoreAuthenticationProvider auth =
        (ICoreAuthenticationProvider)graphClient.getAuthenticationProvider();
    OkHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault(auth);

    // Send the batch request content to the /$batch endpoint
    String batchContent = batchRequestContent.getBatchRequestContent();
    Request batchRequest = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch")
        .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), batchContent))
        .build();

    Response batchResponse = client.newCall(batchRequest).execute();
```

Comment: The 401 does not mean that you lack permissions. Which request did you process with the error?

Comment: Can you please provide correlation and timestamp

Comment: @Carl Zhao : Edited the question with code details

Comment: @Shruthi : Cannpt find correlation ID . Have below details though 

sent time stamp : 1602671828968
Client Req iD : 8db310e2-5e7e-4dd6-9927-748916219bca
Request ID : 2312b82c-191a-4c88-8dc0-9533ecf2dff0

Comment: can you please provide the time stamp and request-id correctly?

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this question

Comment: @Shruthi : Yes . This still not resolved .I have below values from Response Object

Comment: Request-id : edbdf492-be2b-4d8f-ba32-2b8c77f285ba

Comment: Client-requestt-id : 3cab20d9-a17c-4387-a81e-1bc6c9bffa59

Comment: Date : Wed, 21 Oct 2020 12:43:05 GMT

Comment: Sorry for the delay Can you please confirm is it working in the graph explorer and please provide an error message let us if it fails in the explorer.